# Android Photoshop PNG Icons appear large and stretched

Tags: java, android, png, photoshop

I am developing for the Android.  When I create icons in Photoshop (and convert them to PNG), they appear larger and stretched within my Android application.  The emulator that I am using is medium density. Does anyone have some tips for how I can create my icons in Photoshop so that they appear normally on the Android?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dpi of the PNG isn't relevant in this instance, only the actual pixel size. How are you displaying the images? If you're using an ImageView, try setting `android:scaleType="none"`. If you're setting its width and height with `wrap_content` it shouldn't matter, but it's worth a try.

Also, if you're accessing them from the drawables folder, try placing them under a new folder called drawable-mdpi. Android should detect that the emulator is set to medium density, and automatically use the resources from the mdpi folder if they exist.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am displaying the images using an ImageView, and accessing the images from the drawables folder. The image has a resolution of 72 dpi and it is 12 pixels by 15 pixels. I just tried putting the image in drawable-mdpi. What should i set the width and the height to? Should I set them in dip? If so, how do I figure out the dip based on the pixels and resolution of the image?

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, I want to reiterate that the 72dpi is, in nearly all cases, irrelevant when dealing with onscreen graphics. You should simply set the width and height to `wrap_content`. Android will determine automatically the correct width and height (i.e. only as large as the image itself) upon inflating the layout.

Comment: Great, thank you for your help! One final question. Should I place the image in all of the drawable folders (drawable, drawable-ldpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi) in order to add support for any screen density?

Comment: You're welcome! Personally, I haven't worked a lot with multiple densities yet, but I believe there are a few flags you need to set in the manifest to ensure that. One thing I can tell you is that it's best to make a different size image for each density. For a hdpi device, a 120 x 160 pixel image will appear roughly 0.5" x 0.67", while on your mdpi the same image will be roughly 0.75" x 1", due to the different pixel densities. So, larger images for higher densities, smaller images for lower densities. For something like your 12x15 it's probably not going to be that big a difference, though.

Answer (score 1):

PNGs can store [pixel size information](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter11.html#png.ch11.div.8) (dpi). That's probably why you see the image larger and streched.

Check Photoshop's image size options, if necessary fix the print sizes so aspect ratio is conserved.

Comment: Okay so the resolution of my icon is 72 dpi. If tried going to Image Size options in Photoshop and changing the resolution to 160 (which is the android medium density resolution). Then, I made sure that the "Resample Image" checkbox was checked. After hitting OK, my image became larger. In my application, it still looks the same, though...Should i be doing anything else?

Comment: ¿Are you sure the aspect ratio of the print size is the same as the aspecto ratio of the pixel size?
Is that's so, it must be a problem on how you are showing the image.
¿Did you try another format? Gif

Comment: My PNG has a 72 dpi resolution. I noticed that when I define the icon in Android, I am using: android:layout_width="45dip" and android:layout_height="45dip". I think this is the problem. So, knowing that I have a PNG that is 12px x 15px at 72 resolution, how do I convert that into dip?

Comment: pixels = dips * (density / 160), for medium density pixels = dpi.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem. I don't know why. I am using Mac. The png file produces by it is extremely large. For example, the normal size should be 8kb, but it's size is 48kb. If a use other editor to edit & save them, the size return OK. Seems that ps is saving some extra info into the png file.